sudo su gets hung in Ubuntu 20.04
When trying to run the sudo su command it gets hung. If I press Ctrl zz then after 2 minutes it goes to sudo. When I checked the permissions, it is OK and there is no output from it.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].
